# Assign template to descendant category pages in wordpress - but not parent category page

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories

I've got a Wordpress structure like this.

HOME
HOME > BLOGS
HOME > BLOGS > BLOGNAME1 > SINGLE PAGES
HOME > BLOGS > BLOGNAME2 > SINGLE PAGES
HOME > BLOGS > BLOGNAME3 > SINGLE PAGES

I'd like the BLOGNAME1, BLOGNAME2, BLOGNAME3 category pages to use the same template.

From what I can tell, I'm after something to put in functions.php that says if category is a descendant of the BLOGS category, its category page should use a particular template.

There are some similar discussions here but they'd all force these subcategories to inherit the BLOGS template, which isn't what I'm after.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Category Template Hierarchy Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-template-hierarchy/) I built. Then just create your template and name it according to the plugin's naming convention. In your case...

`child-of-category-blogs.php`

..that is, if your slug for that category is `blogs`.